# changing the links to dropdowns in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I watched this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGeAYd3idBc and I was able to create a multilingual application but I need help. I'm trying to create a drop-down box with the text French and English as opposed to the two list item links that I have now in my view. Does anyone know how to do this?
Here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MultiLanguage.Controllers
{
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
// GET: Language
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Change(String LanguageAbbrevation)
{
    if(LanguageAbbrevation !=null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =     CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);
    }
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
    cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    return View("Index");
}
```

}
Here is my View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<ul>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("English","Change","Language",new {LanguageAbbrevation  = "en"}, null)</li>


<li>@Html.ActionLink("French", "Change", "Language", new {LanguageAbbrevation = "fr" }, null)</li>
<li>@DateTime.Now.ToString()</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the controller and model:

```
public class LanguageModel 
{
    public List<SelectListItem> LanguageList { get; set; }
    public string LanguageAbbrevation { get; set; }

    public static List<SelectListItem> GetList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "English", Value = "en" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "French", Value = "fr" },
        };

        return list;
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AAIndex()
    {
        LanguageModel securityQuestionModel = new LanguageModel();
        securityQuestionModel.LanguageList = LanguageModel.GetList();

        return View("AAIndex", securityQuestionModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Change(String LanguageAbbrevation)
    {
        if (LanguageAbbrevation != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);
        }
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
        cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return View("AAIndex");
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@model Testy2.Controllers.LanguageModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Change", "Home"))
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", "Change", "Home", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "en" }, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("French", "Change", "Home", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "fr" }, null)</li>
        <li>@DateTime.Now.ToString()</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Language Dropdown</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageAbbrevation, new SelectList(Model.LanguageList, "Value", "Text",
                "English"),
                 new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })

    </div>
}
```